# COBOL DB2 Bind Process

Tags: db2, bind, cobol

What is the difference between `pre-compile` and `bind` for a **COBOL DB2** program.

How does syntax check differ in both the processes.

If we give the wrong column name in our code, then in which process it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to do some study in the Db2 Knowledge Centre.

A pre-compile action creates a bindfile, containing the static SQL present in the source code (i.e the sections of code with EXEC SQL statements in your COBOL), in addition to a compilable form of the source code that contains the non-SQL logic and data (your PROCEDURE DIVISION and DATA DIVISION etc).

A bind action uses both the bindfile and the database to create a package inside the database which is the executable form of the bindfile contents. The package contains sections corresponding your your EXEC SQL blocks for static SQL.

Later, when the built (i.e. compiled and linked) application executes, and wants to use the database, this will cause sections of the package to be loaded from the database catalog (or read from cache) and executed by the database manager to deliver the required actions.

As each command (precompile, vs bind) serves a different purpose, the syntax varies , and also can vary with the Db2-server platform (Z/OS , i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows) and version.

Refer to the free Db2 Knowledge Center for your version of Db2 and your Db2-server platform (separate different documentation Knowledge Center websites exist for Db2-for-Z/OS,  Db2 for i-series,  Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows ).